# Problem in pushing a value to an element of struct in Julia

Tags: struct, julia

Say I have a struct:

```
mutable struct DataHolder
    data1::Vector{Float64}
    data2::Vector{Float64}
    function DataHolder()
        emp = Float64[]
        new(emp, emp)
    end
end
d = DataHolder()
```

When I try to push a value to only one element of struct `d` by doing:

```
push!(d.data1, 1.0)
```

the value is pushed not only `d.data1` but also `d.data2`. Indeed, the REPL says

```
julia> d
DataHolder([1.0], [1.0])
```

How can I push a value to only one element of the struct??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is not in `push!`, but rather in the inner constructor of `DataHolder`. Specifically:

```
emp = Float64[]
new(emp, emp)
```

This code pattern means that the fields of the new `DataHolder` both point toward the same array (in memory). So if you mutate one of them (say, via `push!`), you also mutate the other.

You could instead replace those two lines with:

```
new(Float64[], Float64[])
```

to get the behaviour you want.

More generally, although it is not forbidden, your use of the inner constructor is a bit odd. Typically, inner constructors should have a method signature corresponding exactly to the fields of your struct, and the inner constructor itself is typically only used to provide a set of universal tests that any new `DataHolder` should undergo.

Personally I would re-write your code as follows:

```
mutable struct DataHolder
    data1::Vector{Float64}
    data2::Vector{Float64}
    function DataHolder(data1::Vector{Float64}, data2::Vector{Float64})
        #Any tests on data1 and data2 go here
        new(data1, data2)
    end
end
DataHolder() = DataHolder(Float64[], Float64[])
```

If you don't need to do any universal tests on `DataHolder`, then delete the inner constructor entirely.

Final food for thought: Does `DataHolder` really need to be mutable? If you only want to be able to mutate the arrays in `data1` and `data2`, then `DataHolder` itself does not need to be mutable, because those arrays are already mutable. You only need `DataHolder` to be mutable if you plan to completely re-allocate the values in those fields, e.g. an operation of the form `dh.data1 = [2.0]`.

**UPDATE AFTER COMMENT:**
Personally I don't see anything wrong with `DataHolder() = DataHolder(Float64[], ..., Float64[])`. It's just one line of code and you never have to think about it again. Alternatively, you could do:

```
DataHolder() = DataHolder([ Float64[] for n = 1:10 ]...)
```

which just splats an a vector of empty vectors into the constructor arguments.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Although I simplified the DataHolder for question-purpose, in my actual code, the DataHolder has 10  elements and I have to declare DataHolder multiple times. So, writing `DataHolder(Float64[], Float64[], Float64[], ..., Float64[])` multiple times seems rather awkward for me. I would be grateful if you give me your opinion about this.

Comment: @orematasaburo I'm not sure I understand what you mean about writing it "multiple times". Nonetheless, I've taken a guess at your meaning and added an update to the bottom of my answer. Hope it helps!

Comment: I don't see how using `emp` ten times is less awkward, but if so, you can define `emp() = Float64[]` and then use `new(emp(), emp())`

Comment: Oh, and also `DataHolder([], [])` should work directly, since `[]` gets promoted to `Float64[]`.

Answer (score 0):

@ColinTBowers has answered your question. Here is a very simple and a more general implementation:

```
struct DataHolder  # add mutable if you really need it
    data1::Vector{Float64}
    data2::Vector{Float64}
end
DataHolder() = DataHolder([], [])
```

Perhaps you'd like to allow other types than `Float64` (because why wouldn't you?!):

```
struct DataHolder{T}
    data1::Vector{T}
    data2::Vector{T}
end
DataHolder{T}() where {T} = DataHolder{T}([], [])
DataHolder() = DataHolder{Float64}()  # now `Float64` is the default type.
```

Now you can do this:

```
julia> DataHolder{Rational}()
DataHold{Rational}(Rational[], Rational[])

julia> DataHolder()
DataHold{Float64}(Float64[], Float64[])
```